# Can I use CartThrob as an AdManager for my site?

Tags: cartthrob

I'm thinking if it is possible to use cartThrob as an Advertising manager for automating payments and recurring subriscriptions ad-banners?

Like if i have a link on a website 'Advertise w/ Us' and when click shows up a table for vacant advertising slot with prices per month and types of banners...Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use it for that. [CartThrob Subscriptions](https://www.cartthrob.com/site/product_detail/subscriptions) can handle the recurring billing aspect. Each slot can be a variation, and you can build logic to show or not show options based on what's available or not.